# Reinstalling/fixing Ubuntu (with disk encryption) after failed release upgrade

Tags: upgrade, 22.04

I was doing a release upgrade of my system. I accidentally got locked out of the lock screen, but I checked `top`/`pgrep` and it looked like the upgrade was done. So I just decided to shut down the system, which was a huge mistake.

It hangs on "cryptsetup waiting for encrypted device" and it has a bunch of "failed to verify module" "BTF -22" errors, and it won't boot past that. I tried googling those errors but didn't find anyone else with a similar problem.

Following [the general guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation) doesn't work because it doesn't detect any operating system. It only offers me the option to erase and install, or "something else" (which goes to a partition editor). Is this because I'm using an encrypted root? It still does this even if I unlock the encrypted partition on my boot drive.

If it's unrecoverable, I do have my important data backed up, but not really anything else. Is there a way to finish the release upgrade? I think the problem is just with fixing the packages.

*Update:* Tried `chroot`ing and fixing the packages while in a live iso. apt was basically completely broken and telling me to `dpkg --configure -a`, and running that also doesn't work (a bunch of the configures fail and it exits due to too many errors)

*Update #2:* In a chroot, `dpkg --configure -a` fails because none of the packages configure properly. Some of the errors were that it couldn't create `/dev/null` as well. Using `apt` in a chroot also fails, `apt update` doesn't work because all the signatures are wrong (maybe due to the failed upgrade) and `apt -o Dir=<root of my main drive>` also can't upgrade the packages because it tells me to `--fix-broken install` which tells me to dpkg configure.

If there's a way to fix dpkg packages of my boot drive while in the live environment (and probably fix my initramfs stuff in `/boot` as well) that would probably fix the problem.